When to make a new tag?
Two new tags have recently been added that I was unsure about, IQ and Excutive-Function. My reasoning behind this is that they seemed too specific and already covered by the tag of measurement. However, this is my personal opinion with little evidence to back it up, so I thought I would put out the question to the community.
What heuristics should be used to determine if a new tag is needed or not?

We didn't have an executive-function tag already? Wow. That was one of my original favorite tags, which I just assumed existed.

I made the executive-function tag, and I was also suprised that it didn't exist previously.  To my mind, a measurement tag is about methodology, whereas executive function is a specific capability of the human cognitive system, so I'm not sure I see how one would subsume the other.
On a more general note, I have no particular philosophy on when to create a tag (I think this is the first one I've made).

Not to cover the full issue, but I disagreed with the creation of the iq tag. I think that intelligence was sufficient and that iq will dilute the tag. This was followed up by a relative new user systematically retagging a number of older questions that specifically related to IQ. I appreciate the sentiment of such a user wanting to improve the tagging. However, I think that systematic retagging of old questions should be discussed on meta before being performed.
Update: Just to clarify, I don't have a strong opinion about whether we need an iq tag or not. I can see arguments both ways. My bigger point would be that before mass retagging old questions with a new tag, I think it is a good idea to propose the idea in meta.

Downvoted for now because it isn't clear to me how or why IQ dilutes intelligence any more than working-memory dilutes memory. I think we really need some consensus heuristics, but I don't really know enough about our tagging practices. We have a LOT of very specific tags in the same vein.

@ChristianHummeluhr we have a very large number of (drive by) users who seem to think that IQ = intelligence. Memory and working-memory are also a bit better operationalized and less loaded terms. From my experience, we also get a lot of very poor "IQ related" questions compared to working-memory related questions.

@ArtemKaznatcheev That seems pretty ad-hoc, which was my problem with Jeromy's answer in the first place. I've worked directly with WM and IQ, and I don't see how it's operationalized better than IQ is, so I don't understand this reasoning. We need to make the general system we're using to evaluate tags explicit and transparent, whatever that system may be.

Isn't the fact that lots of users equate IQ and intelligence a reason to add the IQ tag? It helps differentiate the concepts.
